# Subdomain with custom NS record failing to resolve

Tags: dns, tunnel

I am currently hosting a domain `example.com`. On this domain are two subdomains of note, `foo.example.com` and `bar.example.com`. The DNS records for these subdomains are configured as follows:

- `foo.example.com` has an 'A' record pointing to a certain IP. This works as intended.
- `bar.example.com` has an 'NS' record pointing to `foo.example.com`.

As far as I gather, `bar.example.com` and `foo.example.com` should therefore resolve to the same IP address, with `bar.example.com` being resolved via `foo.example.com`, as is my intent. Yet `bar.example.com` is simply not reachable, returning the following from dns.google:

```
"Status": 2 /* SERVFAIL */
```

Precisely how do I fix this? I'm currently looking through the ZONE file, but I've been informed that my configuration should work by most guides online.

In case it's relevant, the purpose of this is to explore DNS tunneling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As far as I gather, bar.example.com and foo.example.com should therefore resolve to the same IP address,

No, that's not what NS records do. (Instead, that's what CNAME records would do.)

NS records delegate the *DNS query handling* to the IP address of their target – the query never actually "resolves to" this IP address; instead it results in a 'referral' reply that causes the resolver to **re-send the whole query to the host at `foo.example.com`**.

That host is expected to be running its own nameserver (BIND, etc.) with its own zone file rooted at that subdomain, and becomes responsible for providing the actual result. (Such NS records are the exact same mechanism by which your whole domain has been delegated to *your* server in the first place.)

That's what allows "DNS tunneling" to work – since the server in question has full responsibility for understanding the query, it's not limited to just doing a DB lookup; it can also accept fake queries with TCP/IP data somehow encapsulated in them.

You can see the interim referral reply by sending the query directly to your domain's authoritative server – it will have nothing in the 'Answer' section; rather, it will have a non-empty 'Authority' section (indicating that it's a referral to some other server) and the A record will only be included as a hint in the 'Additional' section.

```
$ dig bar.example.com @localhost

;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 2

;; AUTHORITY SECTION
bar.example.com.    1800    IN  NS  foo.example.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
foo.example.com.    1800    IN  A   10.147.18.242
```

The next step done by the resolver would then be `dig bar.example.com @10.147.18.242`, and whatever *that* returned would (hopefully) be the final reply.

(Optionally, `+nordflag` sends the query with the 'RD' flag unset, i.e. "recursion not desired", to more accurately imitate what a resolver would do; although it's not needed to get the result above, but it makes certain config mistakes easier to notice by turning misdirected queries into hard failures.)